# Is there a way to "turn off" a modifier when passing through an Empty?

Tags: modifiers, visibility

I have an object being deformed and arrayed along a curve. I was wondering if it is possible to have the objects not be arrayed/deformed once the object enters into an empty's falloff radius, in this case being an empty sphere. Then, once the object leaves the sphere radius, the array/deform continues. Essentially, I do not want any objects (highlighted in this image) to be visible in the empty sphere, but to be visible outside the empty sphere. Any tips or workarounds would be helpful. Thank you!

[image: Can I turn off array modifier as the object passes through the empty?]

Comment: Have you tried the Boolean modifier on a hidden sphere attached to the empty?

Comment: @ZargulTheWizard wow, thank you for the simple answer. That definitely does what I want! Thank you, if you post this as an answer I will mark it as so.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Comment answer echo:

Attach a sphere to the empty with parenting, then hide that sphere from the render. Use a Boolean modifier on the array and the sphere as a target.